# What's the meaning of the error: Point 95406 after end of properties?

Tags: error-handling, query-replace-regexp

What's the meaning of the error: Point 95406 after end of properties?

I identified the piece of code that produces this error (blocking my script):

```el
;; "Fig" --> "Figure"
;; "Figs" --> "Figures"
(query-replace-regexp (concat "\\(\\<" SAFE_PREREFS_WORDS
                              "\\(?:\n?[\s\t~]+\\|\n\\)\\)"
                              "\\<\\([Ff]ig\\)\\(s?\\)\\>\\.?"
                              "\\(\\(?:\\\\[,;]\\|\n?[\s\t~]+\\|\n\\)?\\\\ref{\\)")

                      "\\1\\2ure\\3\\4"
                      nil (point-min) (point-max))
```

`SAFE_PREREFS_WORDS` is variable defined with `(regexp-opt)`

I tried to ignore the error by wrapping this part of code with `(ignore-errors)` but the script keeps stopping. Why? Is there a way to remove or ignore this error?

Comment: Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes, specify your `M-x emacs-version`. (I don't find such an error msg in the Emacs 27.2 Lisp code, at least: `after end of properties`.)

Comment: Set `debug-on-error` to `t`, and show your backtrace. You say you identified the code causing the error, but we likely need to see the calling sequence.

Comment: GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.14) of 2020-03-26, modified by Debian. I'll search for the other things asap.

Comment: The error message is emitted from the function `update_interval()` in `src/intervals.c`, so it's in a low-level function. Showing a backtrace with `debug-on-error` set to `t` as @Drew suggests is likely much more helpful to pin things down. AFAIK, it has to do with overlays, but it's not clear what causes it.

Comment: Good, @NickD. I don't have the C code to search. Maybe OP can pin it down a bit more with simpler code to repro it, and maybe report it as a possible bug if no one here figures it out. (If nothing else, there may be a bug in that the error message isn't very helpful.)

Comment: @NickD You're probably right, I can't replicate the error if no overlays are setted. I'll investigate further.